# How to specify the progressBarStyleHorizontal attribute in a style sheet

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-styles

I want put the `progressBarStyleHorizontal` attribute  in a style sheet.
I have tried something this, but it didn't work.

```
<style name="BarraProgreso">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>      
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">7dp</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
</style>
```

Do you know how could use this attribute within a style sheet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With *"style sheet"* you mean CSS? I'm confused what you try to do... how do you apply that style above to your view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, nitzanj was right the problem is the style. Maybe this is what you want:

```
<style name="BarraProgreso" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:padding">7dp</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
</style>
```

Where using the **Holo.Light** theme gives the following result:

[image]

And this is how you can use your new created style :

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/yourIDProgressBar"
        style="@style/BarraProgreso" />
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to make your custom progress bar style extend the required style like so:

```
<style name="BarraProgreso" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">7dp</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
</style>
```

Note that reason what you tried doesn't work is because you're trying to assign a style value into a drawable, which is impossible. By extending the original style you get all it's attributes while still being able to override any attribute, in case the parent style isn't 100% what you need.

Comment: Thank you @nitzanj it works, but it doesn't look like what I expected. I wanted I progressbar like the one that is shown when you uninstall an application. To have that result I used `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal` directly in the widget , but since that wasn't practical if you have lots of these widgets, I wanted to put them in a styles.xml